# putting '%' in string.gsub() in Lua

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

i have this code

```
local strs = "my dog"
print (string.gsub( strs , " ","%20"))
```

i just wanted the output will be like this `my%20dog` but i got this error

```
Runtime error
        ... invalid capture index
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'gsub'
```

i have read that `%` is escape in Lua.

my question is, how can i apply `%` for my replaced new string (`strs`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
print (string.gsub( strs , " ","%%20"))
```

`%` is used in lua in regex operations eg. `%a` is for all letters [Tutorial here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial)

So as to escape it we need to use `%%` to tell that we are actually looking for a percentage sign and not a regex.

Comment: please note: Lua does NOT support regex, just patterns (which are by far less powerful but have a more lightweight implementation than regexes)